# Remove duplicates from tar archive

Tags: bash, tar, archive

I'm trying to create an archive of multiple text files. Sometimes these files are updated, when these files are updated I use the `--update` option in *tar* to append these files to the archive.

Say we have two files, *test1.txt*, and *test2.txt*. These files are added to archive *test.tar*.

Inspecting the tar with `tar -tf test.tar`

I get as expected:

```
test1.txt
test2.txt
```

Now if I update *test2.txt*, and append it into the archive using `tar -f test.tar -u test2.txt`.

I expect the output of running `tar -tf test.tar` to be:

```
test1.txt
test2.txt
```

But instead I get:

```
test1.txt
test2.txt
test2.txt
```

So how do I shake this tar to remove the older *test2.txt*? I know that after extracting the archive, I'd get only the most recent changes to both files, so this problem might seem trivial in this demo, but I'm actually archiving thousands of 5000-line files so the archive sizes get comically large with repeated runs.

What I'm currently doing is I'm extracting the files into a temp directory then re-archiving each time my script is run. This is obviously very inefficient. I'm hoping there's a tar option I'm missing somewhere.

Comment: AFAIK there is no option to replace file in `tar` command. I would suggest to delete existing file before adding new file. If you are running GNU tar use `--delete`

Comment: You might also look into a different archive format than tar.

Comment: Think of it this way, `--update` updates the TAR, not the files in the TAR.  So it is working as designed.

Comment: I'm open to other formats, usually I'd gzip the tar after it's updated anyway. So are there other archiving/compressing formats that support overwriting old files?

Comment: _"So are there other archiving/compressing formats that support overwriting old files?"_ `zip` can do that

Answer (score 2):

TAR is simply a concatenation of the raw file contents with some metadata mixed in between. As you noticed, updating a file simply appends the file to the end of the TAR and, by convention, the last file occurring in the TAR "wins". TAR does not simply update a file because that could mean that all file contents after the updated file might have to be moved some bytes away to make space for the larger newer file version.

There actually is a TAR option not having been mentioned here which fits your use case: `--occurrence=[NUMBER]`. With this option, you can specify which of the multiple versions of a file with the same name/path is to be extracted or deleted. It would work fine with your simple example. This is how I set it up:

```sh
echo foo > test1.txt
echo foo > test2.txt
tar -cf updated.tar test1.txt test2.txt
sleep 1s
echo barbara > test2.txt
tar --update -f updated.tar test1.txt test2.txt
sleep 1s
echo foobar > test2.txt
tar --update -f updated.tar test1.txt test2.txt
tar tvlf updated.tar
    -rwx------ user/group   4 2022-03-29 19:00 test1.txt
    -rwx------ user/group   4 2022-03-29 19:00 test2.txt
    -rwx------ user/group   8 2022-03-29 19:01 test2.txt
    -rwx------ user/group   7 2022-03-29 19:01 test2.txt
```

Note that `tar --update` will only check the timestamp not the contents and the timestamp only has 1s granularity! Therefore, we need to wait 1s to be sure that the timestamp is at least one second later or `tar` will not add it to the archive. This is especially important when copy-pasting this code.

Simply calling `--delete` will delete **all** versions:

```sh
tar --delete -f updated.tar test2.txt
tar tvlf updated.tar
    -rwx------ user/group   4 2022-03-29 19:00 test1.txt
```

When specifying `--occurrence=1`, only the first occurrence, i.e., the **oldest** version will be deleted:

```sh
tar --delete -f updated.tar test2.txt
tar tvlf updated.tar
    -rwx------ user/group   4 2022-03-29 19:00 test1.txt
    -rwx------ user/group   8 2022-03-29 19:01 test2.txt
    -rwx------ user/group   7 2022-03-29 19:01 test2.txt
```

Unfortunately, for `--delete`, you can only delete exactly one file version. So, you would have to repeat deleting the oldest version until only the most recent is left. It is possible to do it in bash and that would at least be more space-efficient than extracting it to a temporary folder but it would probably be slower because it has to go over the archive many times and each time the archive is basically completely rewritten in place.

I recommend using [`ratarmount`](https://github.com/mxmlnkn/ratarmount), which I wrote, instead. It will mount the archive (without actually extracting it) and expose a folder view showing the most recent versions of each file. Using this, you can create the new trimmed-down archive:

```sh
python3 -m pip install --user ratarmount
ratarmount updated.tar
ls -lA updated/
    -rwx------ 1 user group 4 Mar 29 19:14 test1.txt
    -rwx------ 1 user group 7 Mar 29 19:14 test2.txt
tar -c -f most-recent.tar -C updated/ .
tar tvlf updated.tar
    drwxrwxrwx user/group   0 2022-03-29 19:00 ./
    -rwx------ user/group   4 2022-03-29 19:00 ./test1.txt
    -rwx------ user/group   7 2022-03-29 19:01 ./test2.txt
```

And there you have it. The output of `tar tvlf` looks a bit different with the preceding dot because we used `-C` and specified to archive the `.` folder. Normally, this doesn't hurt but you can circumvent this with any of these slightly more problematic alternatives:

```
tar -c -f most-recent.tar -C updated/ test1.txt test2.txt
tar -c -f most-recent.tar -C updated/ $( cd updated && find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 )
( cd updated/ && tar -c -f ../most-recent.tar {[^.],.[!.],..?}*; )
```

---

If you encounter problems with ratarmount please open an issue [here](https://github.com/mxmlnkn/ratarmount/issues).
Note that ratarmount even exposes those older versions but in well-hidden special folders:

```sh
ratarmount updated.tar
ls -lA updated/test2.txt.versions/
    -rwx------ 1 user group 4 Mar 29 20:10 1
    -rwx------ 1 user group 8 Mar 29 20:10 2
    -rwx------ 1 user group 7 Mar 29 20:10 3
```

The file names inside the special `.versions` folder match the arguments given to `--occurrence`.

---

The above mentioned version in bash with `--occurrence` would look like this:

```sh
function deleteAllButMostRecentInTar()
{
    local archive=$1
    local filesToDelete=$( mktemp )

    while true; do
        tar --list --file "$archive" | sort | uniq -c |
            sed -n -E '/^[ \t]*1 /d; s|^[ \t]*[0-9]+ ||p' > "$filesToDelete"
        if [[ -s "$filesToDelete" ]]; then
            local fileCount=$( cat -- "$filesToDelete" | wc -l )
            echo -n "Found $fileCount files with more than version. Deleting ..."
            tar --delete --occurrence=1 --files-from="$filesToDelete" \
                --file "$archive"
            echo " OK"
        else
            break
        fi
    done
    rm -- "$filesToDelete"
    echo
}

deleteAllButMostRecentInTar updated.tar
tar tvlf updated.tar
    -rwx------ user/group   4 2022-03-29 19:00 test1.txt
    -rwx------ user/group   7 2022-03-29 19:01 test2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want tar to operate in-place all the time, you can use a wrapper like this (inspired by mxmlnkn's amazing answer).

You can add this to your `~/.bashrc`

```bash
# source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71666950/21567639
function deleteAllButMostRecentInTar()
{
    local archive=$1
    local filesToDelete=$(mktemp)
    local shouldPrintMessage=true

    while true; do
       tar --list --file "$archive" | sort | uniq -c |
           sed -n -E '/^[ \t]*1 /d; s|^[ \t]*[0-9]+ ||p' >| "$filesToDelete"
        if [[ -s "$filesToDelete" ]]; then
            if [[ $shouldPrintMessage == true ]]; then
                echo "Found files in archive with multiple versions:"
                cat -- "$filesToDelete"
                shouldPrintMessage=false
                echo "Deleting all but most recent version..."
            fi
            local fileCount=$( cat -- "$filesToDelete" | wc -l )
            tar --delete --occurrence=1 --files-from="$filesToDelete" \
                --file "$archive"
        else
            break
        fi
    done
    if [[ -s "$filesToDelete" ]]; then
        echo "Done."
    fi
    rm -- "$filesToDelete" >/dev/null 2>&1
    echo
}

# tari, tar "in-place"
# - an inconvenient feature of tar is that it never overwrites members with the
#   same name, meaning that operations like --append and --update will not
#   replace an existing member with a file of the same name.
# - tar "in-place" is a wrapper around tar that calls
#   deleteAllButMostRecentInTar after every tar operation
function tari () {
  tar "$@"

  # First we must figure out the archive name. Possible formats are:
  # -XXXf <archive>
  # --file=<archive>
  # Note: Old-style tar option (tar -cf <archive>) is not supported because it
  # is bonkers.
  local archive_name
  if [[ "$@" =~ -[a-zA-Z0-9]*f[[:space:]]+([^[:space:]]+) ]]; then
    archive_name="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  elif [[ "$@" =~ --file=([^[:space:]]+) ]]; then
    archive_name="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  fi

  # If the archive is compressed, do nothing. (the tar operations that modify
  # archives don't work on compressed archives)
  if [[ "$archive_name" =~ \.(gz|bz2|xz|Z)$ ]]; then
    return
  fi

  if [[ -n "$archive_name" ]]; then
    deleteAllButMostRecentInTar "$archive_name"
  fi
}
```